# What is meaning of this ## in this macro from kernel code

Tags: c, macros, linux-kernel

i found this macro in one kernel code..
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/alpha/include/asm/io.h?v=3.0;a=arm#L140

```
#define IO_CONCAT(a,b)  _IO_CONCAT(a,b)
#define _IO_CONCAT(a,b) a ## _ ## b
```

i am unable to understand the meaning of this.Does anybody know this?

**Edit :**

Then here what it will return

```
  return IO_CONCAT(__IO_PREFIX,readl)(addr);
```

Comment: Review "token pasting operator" in your favorite C language book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double hash is used to concatenate two tokens together:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a ## b

CONCAT(x, y) # Gives 'xy'
```

However, such naive implementation doesn't work in case when one of the arguments being passed is a macro itself:

```
#define Z y
CONCAT(x, Z) # Gives 'xZ', not 'xy' as one might expect
```

That is why macro indirection is used in your question:

```
#define CONCAT(a,b)  __CONCAT(a,b)
#define __CONCAT(a,b) a ## b

#define Z y
CONCAT(x, Z) # Gives 'xy'
```

### UPD.

Now consider the concrete example you're asking about:

```
return IO_CONCAT(__IO_PREFIX,readl)(addr);
```

Here `__IO_PREFIX` is obviously a macro (uppercase identifiers in Linux kernel are often macros). It is defined in several [places](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.0&a=arm&i=__IO_PREFIX), [one](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/alpha/include/asm/io.h?v=3.0;a=arm#L203) of them is:

```
#define __IO_PREFIX             generic
```

Now let's see which steps are taken to expand the original statement:

1. Expand `__IO_PREFIX`:

   ```
   return IO_CONCAT(generic,readl)(addr);
   ```
2. Expand `IO_CONCAT(...)`:

   ```
   return _IO_CONCAT(generic,readl)(addr);
   ```
3. Expand `_IO_CONCAT(...)`:

   ```
   return generic_readl(addr);
   ```

Comment: as per your answer i make this code http://codepad.org/MgdFuRIq why this is not working?

Comment: @Mr.32 because 10_20 is not a valid token in C... It is neither a number, nor an identifier.

Comment: hey thanks for your update now i understood whole things...thanks a lot......'

Answer (score 5):

That's [token pasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation). It concatenates the tokens together. So `IO_CONCAT(foo,bar)` would expand to `foo_bar`.

It is defined in C99 in §6.10.3.3:

> If, in the replacement list of a function-like macro, a parameter is immediately preceded
>   or followed by a `##` preprocessing token, the parameter is replaced by the corresponding
>   argument’s preprocessing token sequence; however, if an argument consists of no
>   preprocessing tokens, the parameter is replaced by a placemarker preprocessing token
>   instead.)
>
> For both object-like and function-like macro invocations, before the replacement list is
>   reexamined for more macro names to replace, each instance of a `##` preprocessing token
>   in the replacement list (not from an argument) is deleted and the preceding preprocessing
>   token is concatenated with the following preprocessing token. Placemarker
>   preprocessing tokens are handled specially: concatenation of two placemarkers results in
>   a single placemarker preprocessing token, and concatenation of a placemarker with a
>   non-placemarker preprocessing token results in the non-placemarker preprocessing token.
>   If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined. The resulting
>   token is available for further macro replacement. The order of evaluation of `##` operators
>   is unspecified.

Answer (score 5):

That is the preprocessor [token concatenation operator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html):

> The `##' preprocessing operator performs token pasting. When a macro
>   is expanded, the two tokens on either side of each`##' operator are
>   combined into a single token, which then replaces the `##' and the two
>   original tokens in the macro expansion. Usually both will be
>   identifiers, or one will be an identifier and the other a
>   preprocessing number. When pasted, they make a longer identifier. This
>   isn't the only valid case. It is also possible to concatenate two
>   numbers (or a number and a name, such as 1.5 and e3) into a number.
>   Also, multi-character operators such as += can be formed by token
>   pasting.

Comment: It's standard C, not GNU.  (GCC has a couple of extensions to ##, but this macro doesn't use them.)